# Do I have to wait for the bar close to trigger the alert using pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I trying to learn pinescript, I am creating an alert in tradingview that has the following logic:

- When the price crosses the SMA 20 down, I sent the alert with SHORT message
- When the price crosses the SMA 20 upwards, send me the alert with LONG message

The problem I have, in both crosses, is that the alert is triggered when the bar closes after price having crossed the SMA.

I want it to send me the alert when the price crosses the SMA, not having to wait for the current bar close it.

Is that possible? Or do I have to wait for the bar close to trigger the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Pine Script does not make it easy to use real time data, as they do not like supporting whats called "repainting". From the documentation:

> We define repainting as: script behavior causing historical vs realtime calculations or plots to behave differently.

When you use real time data instead of closed bars, you will execute trades that may not make sense when you backtest.

If you want to use more real-time data, you could execute trades on lower time frames; say, use the 5-minute chart for your trades instead of the hourly. But if you **insist** on using real time data (thereby "backpainting"), you could do so using the `security` function and the built-in crossunder/crossover functions:

```
lowerTF = "1" // this means 1 minute

getSMA20LowerTF() =>
    security(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTF, ta.sma(close, 20))

crossUpLowerTF = ta.crossover(close, sma20LowerTF)
crossDownLowerTF = ta.crossunder(close, sma20LowerTF)
```

Here you can acquire the SMA20 on the 1 minute time frame and check if there is a crossover or crossunder event. Use this data to set up your alert function.